# How do I get a list to print one word per line?

Tags: python

How do I get a list to print one word per line?

> Write a program that takes a list of student names and sorts them to
>   create a class roll. The list of names will be given on a one line
>   separated by a single space.
>
> The program should work like this:

```
Students: Peng Ivan Alan Jodi Macy
Class Roll
Alan
Ivan
Jodi
Macy
Peng
```

Instead my program works like this:

```
Students: Peng Ivan Alan Jodi Macy
Class Roll ['Alan', 'Ivan', 'Jodi', 'Macy', 'Peng']
```

My program reads:

How do I print on individual lines?

Comment: Have you considered a for loop? `for s in items: print (s)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This program will give your desired output

```
items=input("Students: ")
items.capitalize()
items = items.split()
items.sort()
print('')
for item in items:
    print(item)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
print '\n'.join(items)
```

or

```
print '\n'.join(str(i) for i in items)
```

if not all your items are already strings.

Comment: Too complex for such an educational exercise...

Answer (score 2):

```
for item in items:
    print item
    # or print(item) in Python 3
```